# Loop through multiple Arrays in Json file using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, drop-down-menu

Excuse my lack of knowledge as i have never dealt with Json arrays.
I'm trying to create a dynamic Dropdown system where i have The Country DropDown and the cities DropDown,
and i want to fetch my data from a Json file that has multiple arrays in it, here's an example of the Json file i have:

```
{"Array1":["A","B","C","D"] , "Array2":["W","X","Y","Z"]}
```

Please How can i load the file and then loop through these arrays in a way that i can have "Array1" and "Array2" as values in the countries dropdown and then when i select on of the two generate the Cities (What's inside of array1 or arrya2) in the second dropdown.

Any help will be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const data = {"Array1":["A","B","C","D"] , "Array2":["W","X","Y","Z"]};

Object.keys(data).forEach(arrName => {
  $(Layer1).append(`<option>${arrName}</option>`);
});

$(Layer1).on('change', function() {
  const arrName = $(this).val();
  if (arrName) {
    $('.dynamic').remove();
    data[arrName].forEach(value => {
      $(Layer2).append(`<option class="dynamic">${value}</option>`);
    });
    $(Layer2).show();
  } else {
    $(Layer2).hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="Layer1">
  <option disabled selected></option>
</select>
<select id="Layer2" style="display: none;">
  <option disabled selected></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Really don't think this is the expected behavior. Think of the property names being countries and the arrays being cities for that country. OP's data naming convention is a bit misleading

Comment: I suppose that could be true. If so, OP's question could be improved to be more explicit probably. I've modified the answer to match that interpretation in any case.